# Why is this expression for $1/e$ so similar to the definition of $e$?

Tags: calculus, probability

Consider this probability thought experiment:

> A barrel is filled with $n$ grains of rice. All grains are white, except for a single grain of brown rice.
>
> Pick a grain at random from the barrel. Observe it and put it back in the barrel. Do this $n$ times. For very large values of $n$, what is the probability that you never picked the grain of brown rice?

On any given iteration of this procedure, the probability of picking the brown grain is $P_{brown}=\frac{1}{n}$. So the probability of picking a white grain on a given iteration is $1-\frac{1}{n}$. Therefore the probability of picking a white grain $n$ times is:

$$
P_n=(1-\frac{1}{n})^n
$$

And for very large $n$, we get:

$$
P = \lim_{n \to \infty}{(1-\frac{1}{n})^n}
$$

Empirically, it's easy to see that this limit is equal to $\frac{1}{e}$. For example, we can plug in $n=999,999,999$ to get:

$$
\frac{1}{P_{999,999,999}} = (1-\frac{1}{999,999,999})^{-999,999,999}
$$

This equals [equals 2.7182817629](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=(1-1%2F999999999)%5E(-999999999)), which is within $10^{-7}$ of $e$. Now, notice how similar is the limit mentioned above to one of the most popular definitions of $e$:

$$
e \equiv \lim_{n \to \infty}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}
$$

The only difference is that the "$-$" is now a "$+$".

Here's the question my waste bin and I have been struggling with: **how can one prove that**

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}{P_n} = e^{-1}
$$

**or, equivalently, that**

$$
\lim_{n \to\ \infty}{(1-\frac{1}{n})^n} = \frac{1}{\lim_{n \to \infty}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}}
$$

Comment: If you don't already know anything about exponential functions or calculus, it's probably easiest to try to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+x/n)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$; this can be done using the binomial theorem and some estimation.

Comment: Even more generally, we have that
$$e^{x} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n.$$

Comment: If you *do* know some calculus, then to prove the statement I wrote above, it is enough to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln(1+x/n)=x$. But this is not hard: $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln(1+x/n) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+hx)}{h}$ which is the derivative of $f(y)=\ln(1+xy)$ at $y=0$. This is not circular provided that you have some other definition of $e$, $\ln$, etc. in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac kn\right)^n = e^k$$

In fact, you can write

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac kn\right) = \lim _{n \to \infty} {\left( 1 + \frac {1}{n/k}\right)^{n/k}}^k = e^k$$

Because $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n/k}\right)^{n/k} = e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1  + \frac 1n\right)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

As
$$
1-\frac1n=\frac{n-1}n=\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right) ^{-1}=\left(1+\frac1{n-1}\right) ^{-1}
$$
you get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n
=\frac1{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n-1}\right)^n}
=\frac1{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n-1}\right)·\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n-1}\right)^{n-1}}
$$